# Is this definite integral positive?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

I have a doubt and I am not able to prove (or disprove):

- Let $f(x)$ be an odd function with $f(x)>0\,\,\,\forall x\in (0,+\infty)$.
- Let $g(x)$ be a non-negative function: $g(x)\geq 0\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$
- Also suppose $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^0g(x)\,dx<\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)\,dx.$

I wonder if one can assure that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx>0.$$

**EDIT 1**: Has been  proved (by Adrian Keister) that my thesis is false.

Now I wonder again if is possible add another hypothesis about $g(x)$ to assure my thesis.

**EDIT 2**:The problem arrives from here:

[image]

blue line is $f(x)= \left(e^{-\frac{\cosh ^2(u-1)}{2 }}-e^{-\frac{\cosh ^2(1+u)}{2 }}\right)$ and orange line is $g(x)=e^{-\frac{u^2}{2 }}\cos ^2\left(\frac{\pi  (u-1)}{4 }\right)$ and the function $f(x)g(x)$ graphic

[image]

As we can see in the graph, the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)g(x)\,dx$ seems to be positive.

We can translate the factor $e^{-u^2/2}$ from $g(x)$ to $f(x)$ (in this case the third hypothesis is not fulfilled):

[image]

Comment: Can you assume the integral of $g$ is finite? I don't think it would make sense to compare negative with positive infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should say not. Counterexample: 
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-1/(10x^2), \; &x\in(-\infty,-1) \\ 
-1, \; &x\in[-1,0) \\
0, \; &x=0 \\
1, \; &x\in(0,1] \\
1/(10x^2), \; &x\in(1,\infty)
\end{array}\right\}, \\
g(x)&=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0,\;&x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(0,1)\cup(2,\infty) \\ 
1/2, &x\in[-1,0] \\ 
1, &x\in[1,2] \; \end{array}\right\}.
\end{align*}

If you replace the $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^0g(x)\,dx<\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)\,dx$ condition with the (stronger) condition $g(-x)<g(x)\;\forall\,x>0,$ then you have the following:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx&=
\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx \\
&=-\int_{\infty}^0 f(-x)\,g(-x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(-x)\,g(-x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx \\
&=-\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,g(-x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,(-g(-x))\,dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx. \\
\end{align*}
Now, if you have $g(-x)<g(x)\;\forall\,x>0,$ it follows that $-g(-x)>-g(x),$ whence you get
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx&=
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,(-g(-x))\,dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx \\
&>-\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,g(x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx \\
&=0.
\end{align*}

See tomasz's answer for a slightly less strict condition on $g(x)$.

Comment: @popi: Yeah, I saw that. Not sure what you could do in addition. If you say $g$ is even, your integral condition can't hold (you'd actually get the integral in question to be zero).

Comment: Something about monotony, absolute or relative extremes, etc ... of $ g (x) $.

Comment: What about $g(-x)<g(x)\;\forall\,x>0?$

Comment: See tomasz's answer for a slightly less restrictive condition on $g(x)$ that works. I think my proof could be adapted slightly for tomasz's condition.

Comment: Your way of positioning commas and periods in your piecewise definitions seems very strange. I would write $$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1/(10x^2), \; &x\in(-\infty,-1), \\ 
-1, \; &x\in[-1,0), \\
0, \; &x=0, \\
1, \; &x\in(0,1], \\
1/(10x^2), \; &x\in(1,\infty). \end{cases} $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Why so many commas? I'm following N. David Mermin's "Math as Prose" rule, where typeset mathematics is supposed to function inside English grammar rules. So there's a comma after the definition of $f$, and a period after the definition of $g$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister : We will do A, B, C, and D. Why all the commas in the foregoing sentence? It's essentially the same thing. Now look at this: $$g(x)=\begin{cases}
0,\;&x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(0,1)\cup(2,\infty) \\ 
1/2, &x\in[-1,0] \\ 
1, &x\in[1,2] \; \end{cases}.$$ Can you tell that that period has anything to do with what comes before it?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I'd certainly grant that if piece-wise defined functions had a closing curly brace, it would be more obvious. That, unfortunately, is not the convention for piece-wise defined functions. Not much I can do about that.

Comment: @AdrianKeister : There are two things you can do about that: (1) format it the way I did above, and (2) use the closing curly brace. The standard convention makes sense in a "displayed" context or when nothing follows the piecewise definition. I've sometimes included the closing curly brace in a two-piece definition when something follows it, thus: $\cdots\cdots = \text{something}. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: How's about that?

Answer (score 2):

If for almost all positive $x$ you have $g(x)\geq g(-x)$ and that there is a non-null set of $x$ such that $g(x)\neq g(-x)$, then this integral will always be positive.

No other hypothesis on $g$ will suffice (for all $f$). If $g(x)=g(-x)$ almost everywhere, then the integral is clearly zero. Otherwise, suppose $A\subseteq [0,\infty)$ is a set of positive measure such that for $x\in A$ we have $g(x)< g(-x)$. We may assume without loss of generality that for all $x\in A$ we have $g(-x)>g(x)+1/n$ for some positive integer $n$.

Now, take for $f$ an odd function such that $f(x)=2n/\lvert A\rvert$ for $x\in A$ and $f(x)<\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert g(t)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^{-1}$ for positive $x\notin A$.

Then $\int_{A\cup -A} f(t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t<-2$ and $\left\lvert \int_{(A\cup -A)^c} f(t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right\rvert\leq 1$.